# How to add new block in category page?

Tags: magento2, template, category-products

I try to add a new block in the `category_view.xml` for the footer `sesion` I don't see my new block any idea?

```
  <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="category/banner_category_footer.phtml" name="banner_category_ptk"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

Above code is placed in `app/design/frontend/Special/cali/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`

and the file template is

```
app/design/frontend/Special/cali/Magento_Catalog/templates/category/banner_category_footer.phtml
```

Answer (score 1):

Try moving catalog_category_view.xml to:

```
app/code/Special/cali/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml
```

and banner_category_footer.phtml to:

```
app/code/Special/cali/view/frontend/templates/category/banner_category_footer.phtml
```

Re-compile & re-deploy your site.

```
php -d memory_limit=1024M bin/magento setup:di:compile
rm -rf var/di var/generation/* var/view_preprocessed pub/static/*
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: I don't understand in magento 2, only worked in the module and not for the templates

Answer (score 1):

Just Update as per following:

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-container">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Catalog::category/banner_category_footer.phtml" name="banner_category_ptk"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Hi @Salma its working fine for foolter but i wants to add after category product title.

Comment: Just add in as follows  `<referenceContainer name="columns.top">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Catalog::category/banner_category_footer.phtml" name="banner_category_ptk" before="page.main.title"/>
</referenceContainer>`

Comment: @SalmaSaiyad, will it load after category products?

Comment: @shivashankarm. i need to move after category products, before the footer

Comment: <referenceContainer name="category.view.content">
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Category"
               name="category.view.reward"
               template="Vendor_Module::category/form.phtml"
               after="content">
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>

Comment: Try with above code once